# Using 'or' in Liquid for optional template variable

Tags: templates, jekyll, liquid

I have a small Jekyll-powered site that uses the default Liquid templating engine. I'm converting it to use [Gekyll](https://github.com/jsvine/gekyll), which overrides the standard `page.date` template variable with a Git timestamp, so I need to override the date with a `page.original_date` value declared in the front matter just for older posts.

In my template, I'd like to be able to do this:

```
<span class="date">{% page.original_date or page.date | date: "%B %-d, %Y" }}</span>
```

That doesn't appear to work, so I'm doing this:

```
<span class="date">
{% if page.original_date %}
    {{ page.original_date | date: "%B %-d, %Y" }}
{% else %}
    {{ page.date | date: "%B %-d, %Y" }}
{% endif %}
</span>
```

It's not a big deal, but cumbersome enough to look for a better solution. Does the logic in Liquid allow for a fallback variable like in my first attempt?

Comment: fyi, if you did `{{page.original_date | jsonify}}`, if no value exists, it will output `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{% page.original_date or page.date | date: "%B %-d, %Y" }}` logic isn't correct to me in the first place.

`or` operator is definitely supported in Liquid, but it is a conditional-OR operator performing a logical-OR like other normal programming languages.

However, what you want to is a fallback thing, like ternary operator.

For example, similarly to C#'s [?? Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [?: Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
{% page.original_date ?? page.date | date: "%B %-d, %Y" }}
{% page.original_date ? page.original_date : page.date | date: "%B %-d, %Y" }}
```

Unfortunately, I don't think it exists in Liquid. See this [Ternary operator support isssue](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/236) at Liquid's issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful! I was thinking in terms of Javascript, where you might say "weight = weight || 180" in case it wasn't defined in a function or something. Cheers.

Comment: @ChrisWilson: No worries. More reading about `?:` operator is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Answer (score 8):

In terms of looking for a ternary operator, I think this is the simplest syntax you can use:

```
{% assign original_date = page.original_date %}
{% unless original_date %}{% assign original_date = page.date %}{% endunless %}
{% unless original_date %}{% assign original_date = date: "%B %-d, %Y" %}{% endunless %}
```

Not very readable or concise, but at least it works!

Comment: Thanks, this does the job perfectly!

Comment: does the job but it's the same as using if... else statements, the idea of the question is having a shorthand alternative one-liner